# docker compose failing (syslog ERROR:Unknown interface index 335 seen even after reload)

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

Thank you for checking this.

Ubuntu 18 server on AWS EC2, docker-compose up was running just fine, suddenly it stopped building after a reboot. Not sure what changed.

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: "no"
    command: gulp serve --max_new_space_size=8192 --max-old-space-size=8192 -LLLL
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app/code
    ports:
      - "8050:8000"
      - "8005:8005"
      - "8888:8888"
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.10.3
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /app/code
WORKDIR /app

# Install JavaScript requirements
COPY package.json /app/
COPY package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install -d
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
# Link gulp
RUN ln -s /app/node_modules/.bin/gulp /usr/bin/gulp

COPY . /app/code/
WORKDIR /app/code

RUN export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
# Build webpack files
RUN gulp build
EXPOSE 8000
CMD gulp serve
```

I see some errors in the syslog, not sure if it is related.

```
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52500.188965] docker0: port 1(veth638f141) entered blocking state
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52500.188968] docker0: port 1(veth638f141) entered disabled state
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52500.189101] device veth638f141 entered promiscuous mode
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-networkd[734]: veth638f141: Link UP
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 networkd-dispatcher[947]: WARNING:Unknown index 338 seen, reloading interface list
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-udevd[5940]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-udevd[5940]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth3a08f68: No such file or directory
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-udevd[5941]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-udevd[5941]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth638f141: No such file or directory
Jun  2 15:25:24 ip-10-0-1-194 containerd[993]: time="2021-06-02T15:25:24.995557031Z" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/7712e133ca3de4a4d407341b7a51428e984c4bcbf2311e27ffbd43cbff56ef44 pid=6001
Jun  2 15:25:25 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52500.489989] eth0: renamed from veth3a08f68
Jun  2 15:25:25 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-networkd[734]: veth638f141: Gained carrier
Jun  2 15:25:25 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-networkd[734]: docker0: Gained carrier
Jun  2 15:25:25 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52500.509809] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth638f141: link becomes ready
Jun  2 15:25:25 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52500.509869] docker0: port 1(veth638f141) entered blocking state
Jun  2 15:25:25 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52500.509870] docker0: port 1(veth638f141) entered forwarding state
Jun  2 15:25:26 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-networkd[734]: veth638f141: Gained IPv6LL
Jun  2 15:25:27 ip-10-0-1-194 containerd[993]: time="2021-06-02T15:25:27.979112078Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=7712e133ca3de4a4d407341b7a51428e984c4bcbf2311e27ffbd43cbff56ef44
Jun  2 15:25:27 ip-10-0-1-194 dockerd[1010]: time="2021-06-02T15:25:27.979239439Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=7712e133ca3de4a4d407341b7a51428e984c4bcbf2311e27ffbd43cbff56ef44 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52503.292104] docker0: port 1(veth638f141) entered disabled state
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52503.292214] veth3a08f68: renamed from eth0
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-networkd[734]: veth638f141: Lost carrier
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-udevd[6146]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-networkd[734]: veth638f141: Link DOWN
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52503.350623] docker0: port 1(veth638f141) entered disabled state
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52503.353895] device veth638f141 left promiscuous mode
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 kernel: [52503.353912] docker0: port 1(veth638f141) entered disabled state
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 networkd-dispatcher[947]: WARNING:Unknown index 337 seen, reloading interface list
Jun  2 15:25:28 ip-10-0-1-194 networkd-dispatcher[947]: **ERROR:Unknown interface index 337 seen even after reload**
Jun  2 15:25:29 ip-10-0-1-194 systemd-networkd[734]: docker0: Lost carrier
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? I get similar logs on ubuntu 20.04 but not on compose